# How to escape backslashes in files

Tags: php, python

I am trying to work on a script but I am stuck in one place.

Eg. To get a php output I have used..

```
str_php = """
<?php
echo "Hello World!";
?>"""

php_file = open("index.php", "w")
php_file.write(str_php)
php_file.close()
```

Ok, so I get the output as it is....

```
<?php
echo "Hello World!";
?>
```

So my php code is running. all good till here. But, the problem starts from when I try using `"\"` and `"\n"` and `"\r"`

```
str_php = """
<?php
echo "Hello World!"; \n echo "How are you"; \n echo "God bless you";
?>"""

php_file = open("index.php", "w")
php_file.write(str_php)
php_file.close()
```

But here I dont get the output as it is.

```
<?php
echo "Hello World!"; 
 echo "How are you"; 
 echo "God bless you";
?>
```

And the "\" it just vanishes... at an output.
Eg. I want an output of a php hyperlink something like...

```
str_php = """<?php
print("<a href=\"$dirArray[$index]\">$dirArray[$index]</a>");
?>"""

php_file = open("index.php", "w")
php_file.write(str_php)
php_file.close()
```

and the output I get is...

```
<?php
print("<a href="$dirArray[$index]">$dirArray[$index]</a>");
?>
```

The "\" is missing and the php does not run creating error.

```
print("<a href=\"$dirArray[$index]\">$dirArray[$index]</a>") - Original
print("<a href="$dirArray[$index]">$dirArray[$index]</a>") - python output
```

Can any one help me out with "\", "\n", "\r" ??

Comment: Have you try declaring your strings with an `r` in front? `r'''write your string here'''`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use "\" to escape the "\" character.

Since it is common to want to have long strings containing several "\", Python also allows one
to prefix the string opening quotes if ar `r` (for  "raw") - inside such
a string, no escaping of "\n" to chr(10) or "\t" to chr(9) happens:

```
>>> print (r"Hello \n world!")
Hello \n world!
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your "\" with another backslash writting it as "\\".

Answer (score -1):

If you use `"\n"` it will be parsed and make a newline. Try to use `'\n'`, strings enclosed in `'\n'` are not parsed and it should print out as you want it to.

Comment: The problem is in Python code, not PHP code. Python does not handle single and double quotes differently, except in how you need to escape the same kind of quotes within them.

Comment: Okay. Than why use Python to create PHP and not use PHP instead? ;)

Comment: Thanks guys for quick response... I wasted 5 hours on this and you made it possible in 3 mins. 
the str_php = (r"""<?php echo "hello"; print("<a href=\"$dirArray[$index]\">$dirArray[$index]</a>"); \n \r""") 

worked for me...

As for Ben. I am working on a project on python where it needs to  create PHP page. It could be done in PHP thats true but doing it threw python was a great challange.
Using this you can create and exe python program that will create and index.php page and upload into FTP.

I look forward to more of possibilites then to finding an alternative. :)